# Apache Beam FILE IO WriteDynamic Remove Sink Timestamp

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Hello Guys I'm working with Apache beam and I'm trying to sink some records as CSV on Google Cloud Storage, I had to use FileIO WriteDynamic Method in order to write the CSV with the name contained in a String. My code looks like this:

```
orders.get(validationErrorTupleTag)
            .apply("Convert Validation Error To KV", ParDo.of(new DoFn<ValidationError, KV<String, String>>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
                    ValidationError validationError = context.element();
                    String errorRow = String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s",
                            validationError.getValidationType(),
                            validationError.getValidationRulesType(),
                            validationError.getErrorMessage(),
                            validationError.getErrorElement(),
                            validationError.getOrderNumber(),
                            validationError.getFileName());

                    context.output(KV.of(validationError.getFileName(), errorRow));
                }
            }))
            .apply("Window", Window.<KV<String, String>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
                    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterFirst.of(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(10),
                            AfterProcessingTime
                                    .pastFirstElementInPane()
                                    .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))))
                    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(10))
                    .discardingFiredPanes())
            .apply("Write CSV to GCS", FileIO.<String, KV<String, String>>writeDynamic()
                    .by(KV::getKey)
                    .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                    .via(Contextful.fn(KV::getValue), TextIO.sink())
                    .to(path)
                    .withNaming(key -> FileIO.Write.defaultNaming("error-" + key, ".csv"))
            );
```

The file is writing correctly but with this name:

```
error-helloWorld-2022-03-23T23:14:31.000Z-2022-03-23T23:14:32.000Z-0-00000-of-00001.csv
```

is it any way to write the file without the sharding timestamp using FileIO?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `FileIO.Write.defaultNaming` you can provide your own instance of [`FileIO.Write.FileNaming`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.Write.FileNaming.html) that does whatever you want it to do with the timestamps, shard identifiers, etc.